# WebMatrix- project copied from another computer- relative paths do not work anymore

Tags: iis, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to open WebMatrix project created on another computer.

Problem is that ~/ relative paths are not recognized anymore.

I believe it is a problem with IIS Express settings but I do not know how to solve it.

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Three resources that may help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Working with File and Folder Paths in Code - http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default